# Alter column length in SQL

Tags: sql, alter-table

```
ALTER TABLE tableName 
    MODIFY COLUMN columnName VARCHAR (256);
```

Error :

> Incorrect syntax near 'VARCHAR'

Comment: Assuming SQL server, change the syntax to

    ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN columnName VARCHAR (256);

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for modifying a column definition is depending on used database. For Microsoft SQL Server for example, you would need to replace `MODIFY COLUMN` with `ALTER COLUMN`.

For better help you should specify your database type.